# Audacity and loop: Loop doesn't work properly upon exporting from Audacity

Tags: sound-effects, audacity, looping

I've looped a gunfire sound on Audacity and it loops okay when playing in Audacity.
However when I export to wav or mp3 and play it, it doesn't properly loop.
This is also the case in the game engine so it's not "a media player issue".

Audacity and exported file in: https://easyupload.io/w13ykb

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MP3s often save with some padding, a small period of silence at the head or tail.

Maybe try something like [MpTrim](https://www.mptrim.com) to remove it.

See https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php?topic=78306.0 for some discussion on the topic.

Comment: I read about the padding and used wav instead of mp3, with no solution. Finally got my way by looping the sound rather than repeat-playing it. Apparently the looping of the track isn't broken when exported as mp3 rather gets losts due to padding. I don't know why wav did the same thing though.